# Query to get data grouped by some field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am using `Mongodb` with `loopback` and have the 4models.

`Review`, `Order`, `Product` and `Seller`.

Following are the relationships:

1) `Review` belongsTo `Order`.

2) `Order` hasOne `Review`.

3) `Order` belongsTo `Product`.

4) `Product` hasMany `Order`.

5) `Product` belongsTo `Seller`.

6) `Seller` hasMany `Product`

I want to get all the reviews of a `Seller` grouped by `Products`.

Is it possible to do this directly using query in `mongodb`. For now, I am doing it as follows:

I have a `sellerId` in `review`. So, I get all the reviews where sellerId is say `seller1`. Then I make a query in `Products` and get all the products where sellerId is `seller1`. Then using two nested `for` loops, I form my results. This seem to me be a very bad and inefficient way to do so. Can I directly get the result through some `query` or if not, then is there an optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: please provide samples of your collections